# Id not in set gives no result

Tags: sql-server

Basically if I do the following:

```
SELECT distinct id FROM Table1
```

I get 20 000 rows

```
SELECT distinct id FROM Table1
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM Table2)
```

I get 4000 rows

So when I do the following, I expect to get 16000 rows, but I get no result.

```
SELECT distinct id FROM Table1
WHERE id NOT IN (select id from Table2)
```

-Empty result-

Why is this? Can it be that I run out of memory or something?

Comment: Is Id `NULLable`? If it is, and there are `NULLs` in the column, it will return no results for `NOT IN` queries. Your best bet is to use `NOT EXISTS` instead.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. You should post your post as an answer so I can mark it solved. Note that "id" is just a dummy for the column name - I don't have id's that are NULL.

Comment: Will do, just going to throw a test case together real quick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `NOT IN` queries, it's safer to use `NOT EXISTS` if columns are `NULLable`, rather than try to handle `NULLs` with some additional logic.

Here's a quick example script.

```
CREATE TABLE #t1 (Id INT NULL)

CREATE TABLE #t2 (Id INT NULL)

INSERT #t1 ( Id ) VALUES (1), (NULL), (3)

INSERT #t2 ( Id ) VALUES (1), (2), (NULL)

SELECT *
FROM #t1 AS t
WHERE t.Id NOT IN (SELECT t2.Id FROM #t2 AS t2)

SELECT *
FROM #t1 AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #t2 AS t2 WHERE t2.Id = t.Id)

DROP TABLE #t1, #t2
```

Full disclosure: I do not work for either NOT IN Inc. or NOT EXISTS Corp.